# How do i append characters to an existing line in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to achieve the following with bash:

Create a file called "file" which contains the following data:

```
line1
line2
line3456
```

I want to append additional characters after "line2", for example:

```
line1
line2 test123
line3456
```

I know that I can use `sed` to replace the whole line (`sed -i 's/line2/line2 test123/' file`). But I am sure that there is a better way to do it.

I intend to modify lines with more than one word in a line so maybe I will need wildcards as well.

Comment: Please post a complete example input and your desired output from that..

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/line2/& test123/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` as back-reference to the matched pattern:

```
sed -i 's/word1 word2 word3/& test123/' file
```

This wil append text `" test123"` in a line that has `word1 word2 word3` text in it.